# Restrict selection to 1 of 4 checkboxes - 2 of which lead to other fields

Tags: infopath

I have a form which currently has 4 checkboxes: Each separate from the other and 2 lead to (when checked) other fields.

My task is to make 4 checkboxes mutually exclusive: when one is checked, the other cannot.

This is easy enough, however, the user can get past this by checking one box to reveal and enter information, then uncheck the box and check another to add additional information.

Please note the form is 5+ years old, has been edited and re-edited to the point it is a cluster (you know what I mean).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with InfoPath but have done something similar by manipulating the SharePoint default forms.

Create a rule that when each checkbox is unchecked, the values get cleared of the corresponding fields that are being shown/hidden.

It seems that you already have a rule in place to show/hide these fields so that part is already done.  Now all you have to do is add an action to change the value when the rule is run.